# How to solve the problem with the packages being turned off in VSC?

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with VSC. Today I saw that when I write code in React, plugins turn off. I will not format the code well, the program does not tell me the names of components when writing the code. Thank you in advance for your help

I tried uninstalling the plugins and reinstalling them, uninstalled the program and reinstalled it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.